# Storing data from MySQL table as CSV using PDO via browser

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have a form that writes data to a MySQL database. I want the user to be able to download their data in `CSV` format after final submission.

My code is currently dumping the contents of the database into the browser, i.e. it is being written to the page, rather than to a csv file. I would like to send them to a link and be given the option to download a file.

Here is my current code:

```
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1', $username, $password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$qry = $dbo->prepare($sql);

// Execute the statement
$qry->execute();
var_dump($qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
$data = fopen('/tmp/db_user_export_".time().".csv', 'w');
while ($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Success";
    // Export every row to a file
    fputcsv($data, $row);
}
```

The current result is a page with a dump of all the data from the table. No file is being created in the location desired. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client doesn't know it is a CSV file (it's just text after all!).

Try to add this BEFORE any output (at the top of your script):

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Basically, you're telling the client/browser that the data you will be sending a CSV file.

That should work.

You can find more information about headers there: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: That's awesome, made it work perfectly, thank you! Don't suppose you live in Vancouver so I can buy you a beer hah? Been trying to figure that out for ages.