# php - fputcsv, new line is not getting inserted at the end of the line

Tags: php, csv

I have an array of array and i am trying to insert the array to a csv file.

This is my code

```
$file = 'a.csv'; //path to the file on disk


$fp = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file);
foreach ($column as $fields) {
    print ($fields);
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

data is this

```
$column = (
       (1,2,3), (a,b,c)
)
```

i want output like this

```
1,2,3
a,b,c
```

But i am getting output like this

```
1,2,3,a,b,c
```

Comment: What exactly is your query? new line not inserted in output csv file or browser?

Comment: new line not getting inserted in csv file

Comment: Could it be that there's a "\n" as newline and your editor just doesn't understand that (like notepad.exe)?

Comment: i am opening it in excel

Comment: actually comma is coming in between two lines

Answer (score 0):

Since  fputscsv is delimited by a new line

> fputcsv() formats a line (passed as a fields array) as CSV and write it (terminated by a newline) to the specified file handle.

Your data input will have to be changed to match the format needed

```
$column = (
   (1,2,3) , (a,b,c)
)
```

Modify  or manipulate the code to acquire the needed format.

```
$column = array (
    array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
    array('a', 'b', 'c')

);
```

There are too many ways to do this for me to demo with out having the actual a.csv output from the starting file but I am going to guess that explode() will do the job nicely. This  places a list of arrays in an array as needed for fputscsv to work.

```
$columns[] = explode("),(");
```

An example of this using database output.

```
$result = $connect->prepare("SELECT type_id, label, type, description FROM content_types WHERE type_id='". $args[0] ."'");
        $result->execute();
        $data = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$columns[] = $data;
```

Also check out the original post and answer for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541506/storing-data-from-mysql-table-as-csv-using-pdo-via-browser).

Comment: the format is changed. still same. I am using an array of arrays

Comment: i am reading the data from a database and converting the results to an array of array. Then i am trying to write the data to a file

Comment: Going to need  the  fetch result  code from the database or the actual array being set to file.  The database results can be in an array or object. This output should be  placed in a container array. It doesn't happen automatically. You'll need to manipulate the results to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine. There is a code responsible for encoding aswell.

```
 $filename = ''; // $filename = 'something.csv';
 $chosen = array(); 
  /* $chosen = array (
  *    array('ąąąą', 'źźźź', 'ęeęę', 'óóó'),
  *    array('łłłłł','żżżż', '1111', '22222')
  );*/

$file = fopen($filename, 'w');

foreach ($chosen as $row) {
  fputs($file, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
  fputcsv($file, $row);
}

fclose($file);
```

output

```
ąąąą,źźźź,ęeęę,óóó
łłłłł,żżżż,1111,2222
```

Comment: file not getting created

Comment: It has to. Take into account that filename variable is empty as well as an array. Uncomment them or put your data to current one.

Comment: yeah that i did. i gave file name and gave the data aslo

Comment: Weird. It works fine for me. Probably you are doing something wrong.

Comment: i wrote the code like this

$file_name = "download.csv";
$file = fopen($file_name,"w");
$i = 0;

foreach ($column as $fields) {
  //print ($fields);
  foreach ($fields as $data) {
   if ($i != 3){
    fputs($file,$data.",");
    $i++;
   }
   else {
    fputs($file,$data."\n");
    $i = 0;
   }
   
  }
  fclose($file);
 }

Comment: Past me here content of $column variable. Do var dump or something.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add "PHP_EOL" end of last field.

Answer (score -1):

I was recently trying to work out how to get a new line using fputcsv and came across this post. I got around it by using fwrite to add the new line.

```
    $aKeys = array_keys($aDataKeys);
    $rTmpFile = fopen('php://temp', 'rw');
    fputcsv($rTmpFile, $aKeys);
    foreach ($aData as $aRow ) {
        fwrite($rTmpFile,"\r\n"); //<------Add a new line
        fputcsv($rTmpFile, $aRow);
    }
    rewind($rTmpFile);
    $sCsv = stream_get_contents($rTmpFile);
    fclose($rTmpFile);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you simpli missing to add a new line:

```
print($fielsd."\n") // if the aoutput is console
print($fields."<br/>") // in case of html output
```

Comment: OP said there's no newline *in the file*.

Comment: There isn't new line in the file, but if you like to print every row on new line you need to add it by your self.

Comment: Yes, I don't debate that. But still that doesn't answer the question.